# Runtime constraint change

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have a `UIViewController` which contain is `UITableView` and `UIView`. 
`UITableView` is above of `UIView`.
When `UIView` is `hidden`, `UITableView` should stick to the bottom of `UIViewController`. 
How do I do that automatically?

[image: When UIView is not hidden.]

[image: When UIView is hidden.]

When `UIView` is `hidden`, `UITableView` should stick to the bottom of `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps to set auto layout constraints:

1) To **bottomView** :

- Apply `leading`, `trailing`, `bottom` and `height` constraints to **bottomView** with respect to parent view

2) To **UITableView** :

- Apply `leading`, `trailing`, `top` constraints to tableView with respect to parent view.
- Apply `bottom` constraint to tableview with **bottomView** which is below tableview.

3) Select the `height` constraint of **bottomView** from storyboard's constraint hierarchy, and take an outlet for it:

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

4) In the method, where you are hiding your **bottomView**, just change the value of it's height constraint to zero like:

```
bottomView.isHidden = true

heightConstraint.constant = 0
view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I would be glad to know the reason why my answer is down-voted, I will improve it if anything wrong in this solution

Comment: Your answer is absolutely true.
Thanks a lot.